# WPF: button width cannot be changed smaller

Tags: wpf, windows, xaml, button, width

In one of the windows of my WPF application, the button width cannot be changed to smaller size whatever I do. I tried change the property of "width" in xaml, drag the button in designer, or pragmatically change it using c#. Even if I created a new button in that window, the width could only be changed to larger size but could not be changed to smaller size. Though there was no error or warning, none of the approaches successfully change the width. The weird thing was, I could change the height of the button smaller or larger easily by dragging, and in my other window, I can change the buttons width and height smaller or larger easily. I am using the same style for all the buttons in all the windows. If I drag the button, there will be no response of it unless I unlock the one of the litlle "knot" around it, but it will look like this:

[image]

The only thing is that I use a notification template for this window and there are some animation effects. But I didn't see any major difference between it and others. Here is the XAML code:

```
<Window x:Class="Timebreak.NotiWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Timebreak"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="TimeBreak" Height="450" Width="450"
    WindowStyle="None" AllowsTransparency="True" Opacity="0.7" Background="#f9f9ff"
    WindowStartupLocation="Manual" Left="0" Top="0">

<Grid>
    <Button x:Name="button1" Content="OK" Margin="358,341,13,72" Click="Submit_Click" FontSize="16" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
    <RadioButton x:Name="radioButton" Content="Yes. I want to stand up and take a break for (minutes)" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="26" Margin="31,105,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="368" Checked="radioButton_Checked" FontSize="14"/>
    <RadioButton x:Name="radioButton1" Content="No. I don't want to stand up and take a break because" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="31,206,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="14" Checked="radioButton1_Checked"/>
    <Slider x:Name="slider" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="40,136,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="374" IsSnapToTickEnabled="True" ValueChanged="slider_ValueChanged" Maximum="30" Minimum="1" Cursor="Hand" AutoToolTipPlacement="TopLeft" Interval="29" IsMoveToPointEnabled="True" TickPlacement="BottomRight"/>

    <!-- Animation -->
    <Grid.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)">
                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="0"/>
                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="1"/>
                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2" Value="1"/>
                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:4" Value="1"/>
                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Grid.Triggers>

    <Grid.RenderTransform>
        <ScaleTransform ScaleY="1" />
    </Grid.RenderTransform>

</Grid>
```

Does ideas about it? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Does ideas about it?

You forgot to post the markup of the custom Style that you are obviously using but you could try to set the **Min**Width property of the Button to 0:

```
<Button x:Name="button1" Content="OK" Margin="358,341,13,72" Click="Submit_Click" FontSize="16" 
            VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" MinWidth="0"/>
```

Please post your all relevants parts of your XAML markup and code if still cannot increase the width of the Button.

Comment: Yes it helps!! Thank you so much!